# whats the best way to separate between /:id to one different id in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

lets say i want to render page to view, by the id of the wanted user

```html
<Route path="/:id" exact component={Page} />
```

but each user will also have a page that he can edit if he is logged from his account, is there  a way to  check the :id before getting into the component? or i have to do it inside the component?
And what do you think is the better approach, different components (1 for edit 1 for view) or one component im doing thing differently inside depands if im getting id of my user(edit) or another uder(view)?

Answer (score 0):

How you handle the user session or the id?. Because if you handle the session with a token the best way to that is creating an interceptor for example in axios, You only need to do a request with token and then get the page for the current user.

Comment: i know how to get the current page, but how do i know i which component to render, the one with the edit mode or view mode, i can do that inside the component, but i was wandering if i can do it outside in the router for examle: <Route path="/:id" exact component={id==yo ? PageEdit : PageView} />, and if its the better way than checking inside the component for the id